# In Chrome DevTools is there a keyboard shortcut to inspect a returned nested structure?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If you inspect something in Chrome devtools it can returned a nested structure

For example...

[image]

I'd like to access this and inspect it using just the keyboard.

Is there a way to do this? I'm trying to not use the mouse for development and I have to give up when inspecting things this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inspect($0)` to make sure its open in Elements panel.
And then you might have to change focus but one focused in DOM view arrow keys can expand the DOM's tree view.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the majority of cases I need it. It would also be useful to inspect data structure results.